# Is there Python function equivalent to fibermetric in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to translate a MATLAB code to Python.
I have this line in MATLAB:

```
B1 = fibermetric(Iblur,65,'ObjectPolarity','bright','StructureSensitivity',1);
```

Iblur is a 2D image.

what is the best way to do so?
I couldn't find a function equivalent to "fibermatric" in python.

thank you in advance

Comment: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_ridge_filter.html

Comment: To be clear: Matlab eferences the Frangi paper (3) in the link I shared